# Reading datas from a .dat file into different variables in python

Tags: python, variables, input

I have a **file.dat** which looks like the following:

```
0.00000000000000000000 0.00000000000000000000 0.00000000000000000000
1.02072021799999990144 0.58931309249999996869 0.01464322176999999919
1.04801084399999999697 0.60506934300000003724 0.02121744689000000170
1.11938267900000010258 0.64627589110000005501 0.03132390833999999791
1.23483727700000001093 0.71293363409999999103 0.03462252470999999804
1.36316318200000008432 0.78702263009999995358 0.02774525518999999829
1.44821317199999999303 0.83612626459999994655 0.01540671738000000054
```

I want to create 3 variables **x, y, z** such that **x** would be an array with the first column, **y** with the second column and **z** with the third column. I have tried with the following:

```
with open('filename') as f:
     file = f.read()

     x = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
     y = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]
     z = [row.split(' ')[2] for row in data]
```

However, this is not working and it gives an error. Is there any simple and easy way to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all as a more pythonic way you can use `numpy.genfromtxt` to read your text as an array, and then get the columns by transposing the array :

```
import numpy as np

with open('text.dat') as f:
    array = np.genfromtxt(f)
    x,y,z = array.T
```

And about your code, it's not clear that what's `data`, anyway if you want to loop over the lines of your file you need to simple loop over file object:

```
x = []
y = []
z = []
with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
     i,j,k = line.split()
        x .append(i)
        y .append(j)
        z .append(k)
```

Or as a more elegant way use `zip()` function to get the columns :

```
with open('text.dat') as f:
     x, y, z = zip(*[line.split() for line in f])
```

Comment: So again, `x, y, z = zip(*f)` doesn't work in this case. It returns something like `[('0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), ('.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.')`. [That's why I deleted my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34239001/revisions) (however I think without that **third part** my answer still can help OP, so I undeleted it).

Comment: @KevinGuan Oh, yep, it should be `f.splitlines()`. Anyway as I suggested `numpy`  is pretty much better approach for such tasks.

Comment: @KevinGuan Yes I'm sure. It also performs better in dealing with numeric types.

Comment: No I meant that `f.splitlines()` part. `f` is a file object, which doesn't have `str.splitlines()` method.

Comment: @Yumnam_G Glad of that. You can tell this community by accepting the answer! ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. `f.read()` return the whole file. I think you need split them, use [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).
2. `file = f.read()` but `for row in data`? I think you meant `data = f.read()`.
3. If you're looking for a more simply way, I'd suggest:

   ```
   with open('filename') as f:
       data = f.read().splitlines()
       x, y, z = zip(*[i.split() for i in data])
   ```

   Or just don't define that `data` variable:

   ```
   with open('filename') as f:
       x, y, z = zip(*[line.split() for line in f])
   ```

   Which gives you:

   ```
   >>> print(x)
   ('0.00000000000000000000', '1.02072021799999990144', '1.04801084399999999697', '1.11938267900000010258', '1.23483727700000001093', '1.36316318200000008432', '1.44821317199999999303')
   >>> print(y)
   ('0.00000000000000000000', '0.58931309249999996869', '0.60506934300000003724', '0.64627589110000005501', '0.71293363409999999103', '0.78702263009999995358', '0.83612626459999994655')
   >>> print(z)
   ('0.00000000000000000000', '0.01464322176999999919', '0.02121744689000000170', '0.03132390833999999791', '0.03462252470999999804', '0.02774525518999999829', '0.01540671738000000054')
   >>>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `split()` across the row and append it onto list, something like this. It's simple though

```
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]
with open('file.txt') as handler:
    for line in handler:
        parts = line.split()
        x.append(parts[0]) 
        y.append(parts[1])
        z.append(parts[2]) 
print x,y,z
```

`x` `y` and `z` contain the first second and third row respectively